# JQUERY ajax to update field in laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to update a field in laravel and it doesn't do anything, I tryed to trace the error checking if the fields are correct and the routes but I don't really know.

```
//js file
$(document).on('blur','#dato-anyadir',function(){

    var atributo=$(this).parent().attr('name');
    var id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var valor= $(this).val();
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).parent().html($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    }else{
        if(!comprobacionModificacion(atributo,valor)){
            alert("hola");
            alert(id);
            alert("atributo " + atributo);
            alert("valor " + valor);
            $.ajax({
             //This is the url 
  url: "/listar/modificar/"+id+"/"+atributo+"/"+valor,
                method: "GET",
            });

        }


        $(this).parent().html(valor);
    }

});


//web routes
    Route::get('/listar/modificar/{id}/{atributo}/{valor}', 'AnimalController@modificarAnimal');

//Controller php

  public static function modificarAnimal($id,$atributo,$valor){
        $animal = Animal::find($id);
        $animal->$atributo = $valor;
        $animal->save(); 
    }
```

Any idea? It doesn't do anything when it reaches the controller

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you dont put this route in except list in VerifyCsrfToken middleware, you must to use:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $ ('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr ('content')
            }
        });
```

and ensure you have meta tag csrf-token on header

Then your ajax code not doing anything after get, valor not changed. so please lookup jquery ajax done method

Answer (score 0):

I finally know what's happening, it was my fault ofcourse.

I didn't had the migrations so laravel tried to update the 'animals.updated_at' . A field that is created when you do the migrations.

My fault.
Thanks for the help!